# javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: Caller unauthorized

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, jboss, message-driven-bean, session-bean

I encountered above exception after migrating an application from QuartzMDB with  quartz-ra.rar to EJB Timers in Jboss AS 6.1 . (As a part of upgrading application to wildfly 8.1)

Exception is occurred at a job that uses following ejb.

```
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
@RolesAllowed({"admin"})
public class PlatformPluginBean implements PlatformPluginRemote {

    // some code here

    public Collection<PlatformPlugin> getPlugins() {
        return new ArrayList<PlatformPlugin>(schemaToPlugin.values());
    }

}
```

Following is the job before migration which worked fine.

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "cronTrigger", propertyValue = "0 0 * * * ?"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "jobName", propertyValue = "PruneJob")})
@ResourceAdapter("quartz-ra.rar")
@RunAs("admin")
public class PruneJob implements Job {

    @EJB
    private PlatformPluginRemote platformPluginRemote;

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {

        for (PlatformPlugin platformPlugin: platformPluginRemote.getPlugins()) {
            // some stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

Following is the job after changing to ejb auto timer.

```
@Stateless
@RunAs("admin")
public class PruneJob {

    @EJB
    private PlatformPluginRemote platformPluginRemote;

    @Schedule(hour="*", minute="0", persistent=false)
    public void execute() {

        for (PlatformPlugin platformPlugin: platformPluginRemote.getPlugins()) {
            // some stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

The exception is occurred at `platformPluginRemote.getPlugins()` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@RunAs("admin")` annotation doesn't seem to work for some reason (jboss bug?)

Same can be done by adding following code before the call to ejb.

```
SecurityContextAssociation.getSecurityContext().setOutgoingRunAs(new RunAsIdentity("admin", "admin"));
```

Answer (score 0):

There's this [issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBPAPP-7685) reported in JBoss 5 which also affects jboss as 6.1, to fix it you can add in file `JBOSS_HOME/serve/<instance>/deploy/ejb3-interceptors-aop.xml`  the `org.jboss.ejb3.security.RunAsSecurityInterceptorFactory` interceptor:

eg:

```
<! - The additional MDB specific ones ->
<interceptor-ref name = "org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor" />
<interceptor-ref name = "org.jboss.ejb3.security.RunAsSecurityInterceptorFactory" />
<interceptor-ref name = "CMTTx" />
<interceptor-ref name = "org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor" />
<interceptor-ref name = "org.jboss.ejb3.tx.BMTTxInterceptorFactory" />
<interceptor-ref name = "org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor" />
<interceptor-ref name = "org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor" />
```

In practice it has presented me some problems, not all invocations the role is propagated and some times authorization error occurs.

Alternatively you can use `Subject.doAs()` in `execute()` method of the MDB. Do not forget to add the login module ClientLoginModule in your security domain.

Comment: Thanks for the info, But I am trying this on **Jboss AS 6.1 not 7.2**

Comment: @KosalaAlmeda Yes you're right, was an error of interpretation of the question. See my answer again.